# What's wrong with this implementation of atof from K&R?

Tags: c, pointers

In K&R page 71, the atof function is using array indexing. I am trying to implement the same function using pointer arithmetic(Because it makes feel like a badass :)).

```
double atof(char *str)
{
  int sign;
  double number = 0.0, power = 1.0;

  while( isspace(*str) )
    ++str;

  sign = (*str == '-') ? -1 : 1; // Save the sign

  if(*str == '-' || *str == '+') // Skip the sign
    str++;

  while( isdigit(*str) ) // Digits before the decimal point
  {
    number = 10.0 * number + (*str - '0');
    str++;
  }

  if(*str == '.') // Skip the decimal point
    str++;

  while( isdigit(*str) ) // Digits after the decimal point
  {
    number = 10.0 * number + (*str - '0');
    power *= 10.0;
    str++;
  }


   return sign * number / power;
}
```

In main

```
printf("%g\n", atof("  123123.123")); // Outputs 123123
printf("%g\n", atof("  1234.1222"));  // Outputs 1234.12
```

What's my mistake ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `atof()` implementation is fine. But printf with `%g` removes parts of the result.

`6` is the default if you don't explicitly specify it. Since the resulting value has greater precision, it's lost. Specify the precision:

```
printf("%.12g\n", atof("  123123.123"));
printf("%.12g\n", atof("  1234.1222"));
```

Or alternatively, you can use `%f` (which would print trailing zeros though).

Comment: Dammit I should have known that :). So is the default precision of %g 6 digits ?!

Comment: Yes (that's including the total width for *both* decimal and fractional part). 6 is the default for most of the printf precision. You can read details in the C standard here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8

Comment: Thank you so much man. Especially for including the standard on this.